# Having trouble finding out how to call this extension method on a Dictionary<T,T>

Tags: .net, class, c#-4.0

I have written and used some class extensions succesfully. However, although I can write the following one, I can't figure out how to call it. This particular one is intended to convert an attribute style key-value pair list to a string.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string AttributesToString<T, T1>(this Dictionary<T, T1> dict)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<T, T1> kv in dict)
        {
            sb.Append(" " + kv.Key + "=\"" + kv.Value + "\"");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The following doesn't work:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dict.AttributesToString() // error
```

How can I call this extension?

Comment: I assume you mean dict.AttributesToString(); ? Works for me... what is the error?

Comment: didn't you try `dict.AttributesToString();` ?

Comment: It wasn't a typo. The problem I have is that I don't get AttributesToString in intellisense. I simply can't access the method (of course with () on the end). The namespaces of both files are the same.

Comment: If you also get an error from `Extensions.AttributesToString(dict)` you are probably missing the using directive for your `Extensions` class in the file where you're trying to call the method, or `System.Text` in the file where you wrote the extension method.

Comment: I have System.Text is the extension method file. That file and my calling files are in the same namespace, so I don't mention it in the using.

Comment: @IanC: You usually have to do a clean/rebuild in order to use extension methods.

Comment: @Jim I tried that, but it still can't see the extension method. It can see other simple ones I wrote, though.

Comment: Correction... I can't see other ones I wrote either. I am using VS 2010 Express. I had these working np in 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some kind of build or scope error.  This works perfectly.  Are your extension methods in another assembly or namespace?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.AttributesToString();
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string AttributesToString<T, T1>(this Dictionary<T, T1> dict)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<T, T1> kv in dict)
            {
                sb.Append(" " + kv.Key + "=\"" + kv.Value + "\"");
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, if I paste this code into a new project, it works. If I paste it into the current project (minus the 1st three declarations), it can't see the extension.

Comment: I was missing a reference to the project. Thanks guys.